# Writing to unbuffered channel blocks, even though separate goroutine is reading from it

Tags: go, timer, deadlock, channel

I have a small timer function, that is used to send the id of the timer to the `expirationChan`, when it has expired.

```
type timer struct {
    id             int
    expirationChan chan int

    resetTimer        chan struct{}
    currentExpiration chan time.Time
}

func newTimer(id int, expiration time.Time, expirationChan chan int) *timer {
    timerInstance := timer{
        id:                id,
        expirationChan:    expirationChan,
        resetTimer:        make(chan struct{}),
        currentExpiration: make(chan time.Time),
    }

    go timerInstance.notifyExpiration()

    timerInstance.setExpiration(expiration)

    return &timerInstance
}

func (t *timer) notifyExpiration() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("waiting")
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Until(<-t.currentExpiration)):
            t.expirationChan <- t.id
        case <-t.resetTimer:
            fmt.Println("reset")
        }
    }
}

func (t *timer) setExpiration(expiration time.Time) {
    t.resetTimer <- struct{}{}
    t.currentExpiration <- expiration
}
```

Running a simple code like this:

```
expirationChan := make(chan int)
newTimer(0, time.Time{}, expirationChan)
<-expirationChan
```

Leads to a deadlock, which I don't understands as `notifyExpiration()` is reading from that channel. What am I doing wrong? [Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/Emzwj6lNF2V) Thanks!

Comment: You have a deadlock because `case <-time.After(time.Until(<-t.currentExpiration))` attempts to receive on `<-t.currentExpiration` before being able to evaluate the `case` statements, but the send never occurs because the other function is blocked on `t.resetTimer <- struct{}{}`

Comment: you have to make one of these channels buffered, but you'll be better off just rearchitecting this logic without having to evaluate a `case` by receiving on another channel